# Upgrade changes Vaadin 7.5.10

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I have the following problem. I developed a Java-based web application, first by using vaadin 7.1.11. Now i decided to use the latest vaadin (7.5.10). After reading the official change log i decided to just give it a try by simply importing 7.5.10 instead of 7.1.11. As soon as I run the application via my tomcat7.0 server, I am asked to enter my login data, so far so good. But here comes the problem: after I enter my username, I have no chance to switch to the password box, since the page automatically reloads, no matter which key I press.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using custom widgetset? If yes, did you recompile your widgetset to match the server side version? You can check if the two versions match by inspecting the browser console logs in your browser's developer console or by appending `?debug` to the application URL and checking the in-page debug window if you are running Vaadin in dev mode.